# Minimum 'if clauses' to check existence of at least one negative value in a list?

Tags: if-statement, numbers, conditional-statements

I have a list of floats and need to find out if at least one of them is negative (or positive, both works). Example could be to check a list of dot products to find out if a point is behind any of a list of planes. 
A straightforward approach is to work iteratively.

```
if( 0 >= firstValue )
    return true;
else if( 0 >= secondValue )
    return true;
...
return false;
```

But this requires a lot of if clauses. Is there a formula to aggregate the values and check for the existence of at least a single negative/positive value? It would be ok to treat Zero as a negative or positive number.

If it is not possible, is there an explanation/proof why it cannot be done?

Why do I want that?
The idea is not to make coding easier but actually to prevent branching. E.g. in shader programs using a lot of conditions can have a negative impact on performance. It's not for convenience or because I don't know the number of values to check.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for-loop around the if Statement and iterate over the list of floats.

Comment: Does that effect the evaluation/branching behaviour? I'm sorry, I was not clear enough. The problem is not to write the code down. The problem is that e.g. in shader code more conditions mean less performance. I will clarify the question.